# Create A session timeout for application

Tags: android

I have many activities in my application(eg A->B->C->D)...A is a login activity...i have a countdowntimer that i am using for a session timeout.. What i want to do is....logout the user.. i.e put him back to activity A if there is no user interaction in the activities B,C,D... i have extended my application class and instantiated my timer in that...But in this activity i cant clear the stacktop of the previous activities i.e the line

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Throws a exception..Any idea how will i solve this problem...Here is my code...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    MyCount count;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // reinitialize variable
        count = new MyCount(5000, 1000);
    }

    public void startcounter() {
        count.start();
    }

    public void cancelcounter() {
        count.cancel();
    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            try{
            Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            my.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(my);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finsihed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(e),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000),
    //              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 12-07 13:36:37.029: E/AndroidRuntime(16109): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Did you try adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as well?

Comment: ok i got the solution.... use flag clear_top and new_task together...i like this
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: I think, this way you'll start another instance of the app.

Comment: ya that is right but the previous instance gets cleared by the clear top flag... right???

Comment: According to docs - no. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: _"instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the top"_. So why not to use additional `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` instead of `FLA‌​G_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? It leaves the previous instance indeed.

Comment: I have to use NEW_TASK because my MyApp class is outside the activities...so i cant call activity from that class using the same task..it gives the same above exception